# GlassFish 3.1.2 PostgreSQL 9.1 = ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, glassfish

I just upgraded GlassFish from 3.1.1 to 3.1.2. My app deploys, but bombs out on any page that makes use of JPA (all of them!).

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4PreparedStatement
    at com.sun.enterprise.loader.ASURLClassLoader.findClassData(ASURLClassLoader.java:782)
    at com.sun.enterprise.loader.ASURLClassLoader.findClass(ASURLClassLoader.java:696)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 168 more
```

Is there some 3.1.2 deployment related change that I've missed?

Also, if it's relevant, I build and package with Maven 2.

**Update**:

As suggested, adding the PostgreSQL JDBC jar manually to GlassFish 3.1.2 has worked, but this is **not** a solution because it should **not** be necessary as it complicates the deployment process and is a regression from 3.1.1.

Comment: If the answer helped you, it is correct and should be accepted as the answer to the question that you posed.  If you think there is a bug in GF, then you should file it @ http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH.

Comment: Fair enough. I didn't want to accept because the outcome was that I had raised a bug (a number of days before you suggested it) and don't feel comfortable encouraging others to install JDBC jars as opposed to deploying them with the EAR. But I accepted because it is *a* solution and the only alternative to not using 3.1.2 at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the jar containing the JDBC driver to the Glassfish installation.

I believe it needs to go in an ext folder under the domain.

Comment: I haven't had to do that with GlassFish 3.1.1. I know that because I regularly blow away my 3.1.1 installation and replace it with a fresh one. Is this a 3.1.2 change? If so, that really sucks because it complicates the deployment process.

Comment: Otherwise it needs to go with your deployment.  Sure that hasn't changed?

Comment: Nothing has changed. When built with Maven, the ear contains the postgresql jdbc jar. I have switched back and forth between 3.1.1 and 3.1.2 to test this and haven't changed anything else.

Comment: In that case the ext-folder does not apply.  You may have hit a bug - have you scrutinized the server log?

Comment: Yeah, there's all sorts of weird new crap in the log. And that's just from a fresh installation of the server running without an app deployed. Reported: [GLASSFISH-18442](http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-18442). I always seem to hit GlassFish bugs for the most basic use cases. Makes me wonder if they do any tests beyond their pointless unit testing. "But it was all green!"

Comment: GlassFish, like many Java EE servers, is a patchwork of various reference implementations. Something is bound to break.

Comment: You may want to add a minimal EAR showing the behaviour to your bug report.

Comment: Accepted, but with reservations. The real solution is to not upgrade from GlassFish 3.1.1 until there is a newer version that fixes this bug.

Comment: Accepting indicates the most helpful answer to you.  If no answers were, then consider writing your own answer and accepting that.